# How to seed data without key in Entity Framework Core 3?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

## Description

I want to seed data into my database. The data hasn´t a key or id value. But for some reason I got the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.get_IsKeyUnknown()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.PropagateToUnknownKey(EntityState oldState, EntityState entityState, Boolean adding, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.IUpdateEntry.set_EntityState(EntityState value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.TrackData(IModel source, IModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(IModel source, IModel target, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I try to add sample data with a key it works. Is it not possible to add sample data into the database without key / id ?

## Code

ModelBuilderExtensions.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using workbranch.Models.Db.Helper;
using workbranch.Models.HonorarTool;

namespace workbranch.Models.Db
{
    public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<HonorarToolLists>()
                .HasNoKey()
                .HasData(
                    new HonorarToolLists
                    {
                        Name = "TGA-MT",
                        Year = 2013,
                        ChargeableCosts = 5000,
                        Zone = 1,
                        MinRate = 2132,
                        MaxRate = 2547
                    }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

HonorarToolLists.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace workbranch.Models.HonorarTool
{
    public partial class HonorarToolLists
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }

        public int ChargeableCosts { get; set; }

        public int Zone { get; set; }

        public int MinRate { get; set; }

        public int MaxRate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AppDbContext.cs

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using workbranch.Models.StatusReporting;
using workbranch.Models.HonorarTool;

namespace workbranch.Models.Db
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }
        public DbSet<HonorarToolLists> HonorarToolLists { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Seed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. When you seed data, you need to see *all* the data, including the PK. This is by design, because you'll often need to seed relationships as well, and that would be largely impossible if you didn't know the key for the related item.

Comment: ah damn. Okey nice to know. I´ve now added the data in the up migrations via migrationsBuilder.Insert.. The only way I found.

Comment: Hi @LukasGund what is solution on this issue ?